# Rails: belongs_to specific column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm, model, relation

I have the following model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  #method that I want to delete and replace with belongs_to
  def restaurant
      RemoteRestaurant.find_by_shortRD(self.INFO_SHORT_RD)
  end
end
```

How can I add a belongs_to :remote_restaurant in this case?

Comment: Can you try `belongs_to :remote_restaurant, foreign_key: 'shortRD'`? I can't test it right now and I don't remember exact syntax.

Comment: what's going on with that INFO_SHORT_RD constant?

Answer (score 0):

Add belongs_to with your custom foreign_key and primary_key

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :remote_restaurant, :foreign_key => "INFO_SHORT_RD", :primary_key=>"shortRD"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :restaurant, class_name: 'RemoteRestaurant', foreign_key: :shortRD, primary_key: :INFO_SHORT_KEY
end
```